# Vue JS - Bootstrap Datepicker not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, vuejs2

I am trying to use bootstrap datepicker in Vue Js by adding it dynamically, but it is not initializing.

**HTML**

```
<div v-for="(aligner,index) in aligners" v-bind:key="aligner">
<input type="hidden" v-bind:name="'AlignerDetails[' + index + '].BatchNo'" v-bind:value="'AlignerDetails_' + (index + 1) + '__BatchNo'" />
<div class='mt-element-ribbon bg-grey-steel'>
    <div class='ribbon ribbon-round ribbon-color-primary uppercase'>Batch #{{index + 1}}</div>
    <div class='pull-right'>
        <a href='javascript:;' v-on:click='remove(index);' class='btn-delete'>
            <i class='fa fa-trash-o font-red'></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='row ribbon-content'>
        <div class='col-md-12 padding-left-0 padding-right-0' style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <input type="text" v-bind:name="'AlignerDetails[' + index + '].AlignersSent'" v-on:blur="calculate();" class="form-control alignersSent" placeholder="Aligners Sent" />
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-12 padding-left-0 padding-right-0'>
            <div class="input-group date bs-datetime">
                <input type="date" v-bind:name="'AlignerDetails[' + index + '].AlignersSentDate'" class="form-control form-control-inline alignersSentDate" placeholder="Aligners Sent Date" autocomplete="off" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#alignerDetails",
data: {
    aligners: []
},
mounted: function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd M yyyy'
    });
},
methods: {
    add: function () {
        this.aligners.push({});
    },
    remove: function (index) {
        this.aligners.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
});
```

I am not getting why this is not working..

Comment: Try moving your initialisation code into `beforeDestroy` instead of `mounted` and see if that helps.

Comment: There are any error on console ?

Comment: if you are using any css or if this is within a modal, check z-index.  bootstrap datepicker uses z-index of 1000 so it might be showing up, but under existing content.

Comment: The repo vuejs-datepicker seems no longer active.

Answer (score 3):

The trick I've found when embedding Jquery elements that require initialization is to place them inside a hidden element using v-if. According to Vuejs's documentation, v-if does not render that element until it meets the v-if condition. So the items are not in the DOM until you programatically set them to. At which case give you a great event to add jquery init statements.

Place your datepicker inside a v-if based div

```
<div v-if="show"></div>
```

Inside mounted I do something like this

```
async mounted() {
    this.show = true

    $('select', this.$el).selectpicker();
    $('.datepicker', this.$el).datepicker({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', orientation: 'bottom auto'});

    //this is how you allow datepicker to send its value to v-model on the input field
    $('.datepicker').change(function() {
        $(this)[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    });
}
```